# Convert errors into warnings with glossaries

Tags: glossaries

Is it possible to convert `errors` into `warnings` and not stop compilation when using `glossaries`?

If P2P is not defined, a message is issued and compilation stopped:

`Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry '3GPP' has not been defined.`

Probably this is a simple feature that I didn't find in the documentation. For example using `acro` with option `silent=true`, or with `acronym` package it is possible.

This is useful because I am copying my own text from other documents to other single document and at beginning just test the layout; and after define the acronym.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{P2P}{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}


\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\ac{P2P}
\ac{3GPP}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\let\glsdoifexists\glsdoifexistsorwarn

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{P2P}{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}


\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\ac{P2P}
\ac{3GPP}

\end{document}
```

I get

```
Package glossaries Warning: Glossary entry `3GPP' has not been defined on input line 14.
```

A different solution prints the offending entry between exclamation marks, in bold face.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\glsdoifexists}[2]{%
  \ifglsentryexists{#1}{#2}{%
    \textbf{!#1!}\PackageWarning{glossaries}{Glossary entry `\glsdetoklabel{#1}'
    has not been defined}}%
}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{P2P}{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}


\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\ac{P2P}
\ac{3GPP}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is a good start. Thanks. However, I would like that something could be printed. In my MWE, 3GPP should be printed as the packages that I mention do.

Comment: @cacamailg Here it is; maybe you can ask for a new feature in the package.

Comment: This would be a very good feature to add.

Comment: How can I ask for it?

Comment: @cacamailg http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/feature-request.cgi